# Can I call a destructor from a private constructor and use garbage collection?

Tags: c#

I have the following code and it runs, but I am not sure if it can be simplified. Can I call a destructor on a Zeroton even if it is NULL?

I think I could simplify my code, but I don't know how.

Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var zeroten = new Zeroton();
        var w = zeroten.ToString();
        var x = zeroten.Equals(w);
        var y = zeroten.GetHashCode();
        var z = zeroten.GetType();
        if(z == typeof(Zeroton))
        {
            zeroten = null;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Zeroton : IDisposable
{
    private Zeroton zeroten;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return BitConverter.IsLittleEndian;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GC.MaxGeneration.ToString();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GC.MaxGeneration;
    }

    public Zeroton()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        Zeroton z = null;
        try
        {
            NullifyMemoryPressure();
            GC.Collect();
            DoNothingForAwhileThenStop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DoNothingForAwhileThenStop();
            SuppressError();
            GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        }
        if (true)
        {
            DoNothingForAwhileThenStop();
            GC.AddMemoryPressure(GC.MaxGeneration);
            GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(GC.MaxGeneration);
        }
        GC.KeepAlive(z);
        GC.Collect();
    }

    private Zeroton DoNothingForAwhileThenStop()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(GC.MaxGeneration);
        GC.Collect();
        NullifyMemoryPressure();
        GC.Collect();
        return zeroten;
    }

    private void NullifyMemoryPressure()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.AddMemoryPressure(GC.MaxGeneration);
        GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(GC.MaxGeneration);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.KeepAlive(zeroten);
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        if (null == null)
        {
            NullifyMemoryPressure();
            GC.Collect();
            this.zeroten = null;
            GC.Collect();
            GC.CancelFullGCNotification();
        }
        DoNothingForAwhileThenStop();
    }

    int? SuppressError()
    {
        GC.CancelFullGCNotification();
        DoNothingForAwhileThenStop();
        GC.Collect();
        NullifyMemoryPressure();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: C# doesn't have destructors.  Presumably you mean a finalizer, but your code has no finalizers.

Comment: To indirectly answer the question asked... You can't do *anything* to a `null` object because that means there's no object to act upon. I would also wager you could simplify your code by not doing whatever it is you think you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a complete misunderstanding about how this all works. **C# does NOT have destructors.** There is no way in C# for you to force the garbage collector to collect any object. Ever.

What you do have are *finalizers*. However, it's important to remember that finalizers deal with *unmanaged* resources... ie, things other than memory. Additionally, we have the IDisposable pattern we can use to call finalizers in a deterministic way... but again, IDisposable deals with *unmanaged* resources, not memory.

In other words, you absolutely can simplify that code, because all those `GC.Collects()` *don't do anything* relative to your `Zeroton` type.

Answer (score 0):

The `unsafe` keyword was created for exactly this.

```
public class Program
{
   unsafe
   {
      var zeroten = new Zeroton();
      Monitor.Enter(zeroten);
      ~this(); // this calls teh destructor
      Environment.Exit();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to enter your monitor. Huh! huh! Droolz. 
Or monitor you entrance.

Comment: See:  `Monitor.Pulse`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.pulse(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GC.OnStrike = false. This will allow GC to create more sanitationWorkerProcesses and GC happens much faster.